# Identification IC: LDO, SOT23-5, Marking HR1zG

Tags: identification, ldo

I am searching for a few days now for what is presumably a LDO.

The package is SOT23-5, marking HR1zG (or with a bit of fantasy HR1z6)

```
[5]     [4]
+---------+
+---------+
[1] [2] [3]
```

1. Vout (I think it should be between 4.4 to 5V
2. GND
3. NC (not 100% sure)
4. Enable (active on Low)
5. Vin

Vin comes directly from a USB connector

It sits on the VPC module of a FLIR Tau2 Camera and is powering the camera.
According to:
https://flir.netx.net/file/asset/12409/original/attachment
It should supply between 4.4 and 6V at 450mA

I think the chip is defect as it gets extremely hot instantly.

Can anybody help me out please...

Edit:

[image: PCB Image]

Comment: It looks like there is a voltage divider on pin 4, which could just be jumpers to select enable/disable.. but are you sure that it's not ADJ/feedback? Many LDOs I've seen follow the convention of AP2204, so there is a chance that Vout and Vin are swapped. Could you measure the resistor the is connected to pin 4? If it is 0 ohms, then its likely that the pin is EN. If it has value, it might be part of a voltage setting resistor divider

Comment: It is 0 Ohms (measured 0.1 Ohms), but good point. I could not identify where the pad with the unpopulated SMD part is connected to and I didn't invesigate further as I thought it is just enable. Will take a closer look.

Comment: One thing I don't really understand is the design itsellf.
Why would they put an LDO between VBUS of USB and the allowed 4.4 to 6V of the cam.
I mean for protection TVS diodes would be a lot better (actually there was a TVS network on the unsoldered 4 pads next to the usb connector.

Comment: Looks like there's an LED on the output of that regulator (if it is a regulator).  Does it light up???

Comment: Yes it is and yes it lights up. The output voltage of the LDO is around 4.6V. The problem is that it gets incredibly hot (way too hot to touch) extremely fast. I would have to check a known ok board to see if the voltage is correct at 4.6V and if it also gets hot.